# spawn EACCESS Error while building Android Platform for Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

My Application is working fine in Browser through `ionic serve` .

But when I am trying to run `ionic build android` ,it is showing

> ERROR: spawn EACCES permission denied

I already installed cordova ,ionic and Android Studio 3 times and even try this :

`chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js`

But the issue is still same. Please suggest me some Better Solution.

[image: spawn_EACCES_ERROR]

Comment: Which version of ionic you are using ? If you are using ionic v1, you should run 'sudo ionic hooks add' command to working with ionic hooks.

Comment: Yes, I am using ionic v1 and your suggestion works for me. Thanks @ Fatih Ayyildiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run this command

> sudo ionic hooks add

Because older version of ionic is using hooks so you should run it first.Thanks