# Capacitor build android returns "Error spawn errno -13 EACCESS"

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using capacitor to build an android project with ionic like so

```
ionic capacitor build android
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
Opening Android project at: android.
[capacitor] node:events:491
[capacitor]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[capacitor]       ^
[capacitor] 
[capacitor] Error: spawn /home/<username>/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.10121639/bin EACCES
[capacitor]     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
[capacitor]     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
[capacitor]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[capacitor] Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
[capacitor]     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
[capacitor]     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
[capacitor]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
[capacitor]   errno: -13,
[capacitor]   code: 'EACCES',
[capacitor]   syscall: 'spawn /home/cedric/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.10121639/bin',
[capacitor]   path: '/home/cedric/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.10121639/bin',
[capacitor]   spawnargs: [ '/home/cedric/apps/scrm/android' ]
[capacitor] }
[capacitor] 
[capacitor] Node.js v18.16.1
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

There's been [a bug report opened](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6116) for this, but unfortunately it's been closed. [A similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739212/spawn-eaccess-error-while-building-android-platform-for-ionic) was related to a very old version of ionic (and not even capacitor), and doesn't help. Other searches have proven futile.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the command again with the `--verbose` command so I could see details of the problem. That's where I saw a more explicit problem:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/cedric/apps/scrm/www/1033.0d4c404c719a46a0.js'
```

Taking a look at the `www` folder, I noticed it was owned by root, and not my current user. So I had to make the change:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER} www
```